# Turning dictionary key into an element of dataframe

Tags: python

My code can get the job done but I know it is not a good way to handle it.

The input is thisdict and the output is shown at the end.

Can you help to make it more efficient?

```
import pandas as pd

thisdict = {
  "A": {'v1':'3','v2':5},
  "B": {'v1':'77','v2':99},
  "ZZ": {'v1':'311','v2':152}
}
output=pd.DataFrame()

for key, value in thisdict.items():
    # turn value to df
    test2 =pd.DataFrame(value.items(), columns = ['item','value'])
    test2['id'] = key

    #transpose
    test2 = test2.pivot(index='id',columns='item', values = 'value')
    
    #concat
    output=pd.concat([output,test2])

output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(thisdict, orient='index')
```

or

```py
output = pd.DataFrame(thisdict).T
```

and if you wish, rename the index by:

```py
output.index.rename('id', inplace=True)
```

Comment: I feel so bad for myself! Your code is so clean. ```d = {
  "A": {'v1':'3','v2':5},
  "B": {'v1':'77','v2':99},
  "ZZ": {'v1':'311','v2':152}
}
print(d)
d1 = {(k1): v1 
      for k1, v1 in d.items()
      for k2, v2 in v1.items()}

print(d1)
# df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1, orient='index')
# #alternative
df = pd.DataFrame(d1).T
df
# print(dict)```

Comment: I also added your solution to the answer so others can reference